# Why did Hwal take his son with him?

Tags: bulgasal

When Hwal goes to confront the Bulgasal that he believes to have cursed him and his family, he is adamant about bringing his son with him, which may be what causes his wife to insist on going as well.

It should probably not surprise anyone that the Bulgasal

> kills his son.

Why did he insist on taking his son with him on his mission to confront what was rumored to be the most dangerous monster of all, one that seemingly had a personal vendetta against him? Most people would not take their children with them to war even if they were safely in the rear, let alone to the front lines of a fight against a vicious monster with a relatively small number of soldiers. Did he believe that his son's physical presence was necessary to break the curse?

Comment: I think its simply just a writing mechanism to raise the stakes. No one would take their blind son to the forest to fight the deadliest monster ever. For some reason he thought it was the only way to cure him? without actually knowing anything at all. The Bugasal kills his family and then he understands how deep the revenge goes.